# Accessibility issue - Tabbed navigation skips the new "Products" menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility

I notice the new product option does not have an option to access it using tabbed navigation via the keyboard:

This is the new drop-menu:

[image]

When you press <kbd>tab</kbd> the focus is passed to all the buttons, except it skips the Products menu.

You can see the button focus here (around the "stack overflow" site button):

[image]

Pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> jumps the focus over to the search box.

Is this a bug or intentional?

Comment: Pretty sure that's just an unintentional tabindex glitch. Sending this over to the product folks to see.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to do that - can you please guide me what the process is?

Comment: I added the status-review tag to this, which automatically puts it on their board to see :) There's nothing else you need to do.

Comment: Desired fix, remove the products button

Comment: @rla4 what will the fix be? My upvote desired fix mentioned above? It will at the same tine resolve nunerous bug reports here on meta regarding navigation on small screens.

Comment: @Luuklag for now, I'm fixing the navigation and making sure we don't skip the Products menu. I don't think we have plans to remove it entirely at the moment, but we surely need to make it accessible

Comment: @rla4, fine either way. But if you decide to keep the products menu it would be nice if you guys fixed the problems that came from its implementation, for example my latest post on this meta amongst others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed. Turns out the Products menu anchor was not focusable because it lacked an `href` attribute. Users should be able to access it using tabbed navigation now.